# What is wrong with my CSV upload code in Django?

Tags: django, csv, django-forms

```
class DataInput(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(label="Select CSV file")

    def save(self, mdl):
        records = csv.DictReader(self.cleaned_data["file"].read().decode('utf-8'), delimiter=',')

        for row in records:
            print (row[0])
```

when I upload CSV file it throws error like

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    0
```

If I print (row), it prints out everything. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) - hence you should use keys to access the fields, not indexes. In other words, `row` is a dictionary:

```
for row in records:
    print(row['my_field_name'])
```

Comment: Do you mean 'my_field_name' is a column name in csv file? If yes, then I tried it also. But it did not work.

Comment: @AlexSh. what do you get when you print just `row` instead of `row[0]`?

Comment: {'a': 'u'}
{'a': 'c'}
{'a': 't'}
{'a': 'i'} 
{'a': 'o'}
{'a': 'n'}
{'a': ','} it prints out in pairs

Comment: @AlexSh. then, If I understand correctly, you need to use `row['a']`.

Comment: yes, you are right. But how do Io retrieve data by csv headers. When I use row['a'] I receive list of all cells

Comment: Thx, at least you gave me a hint how to do it.

Comment: @AlexSh. thanks, could you describe your use case, what is your end goal?

Comment: my goal is to connect with my model and save it to database

Comment: @AlexSh. ok, but why are you overriding `save()`?

Comment: Good question. First I would like to check it with print if it works correctly then I will connect with my model.